# Use of jQuery for creating an interactive skeleton?

Tags: jquery, coda

Im trying to create an interactive skeleton (human type) whereby when a user rolls over a specific point a popup/tooltip appears showing details.

I have a theory in my head as to how I should go about this, it includes a slightly modified coda jquery tooltip script and using co-ordinates.

My question is how others would do this? Ideally I would like it to be accesible to as many browsers as possible - i realise this isnt entirely possible.

Does anyone have a better suggestion than using the Coda for the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the [jQuery Map Hilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) plugin. It's using `<map>` and `<area>` tags, and adds nice highlights. I'm not sure how well it playes with the other plugin, it may take some work.
This has the benefit of degrading into a regular `<img>` with area tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an old-fashioned imagemap, or transparent DIVs over an image to trigger the effect. I'd rather use beautyTips instead of Coda, but that's besides the point.